# how to write a php string to another file

Tags: php

I am trying to write a string to a newly created file but when I write it to my newly create file I see the value of the string, but what I want actually is the string to show like $id = 15; but I only see 15 please someone should help me out I have been on this for hours

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $newfile = "../".$low.$row["page_id"].".php";
    $url = "../".$low.$row["page_id"];
    $create = fopen($newfile,"w");

    $addfile = "<?php  include '../page.php'; ?>";
    $write = fwrite($create, $addfile);
    fwrite( $create, "<?php $id = $pid; ?>" );
}
```

what I want is to see `$id = $pid` inside the newly created file but instead, I see the value it store

Comment: `fwrite( $create, '<?php $id = ' . $pid . '; ?>' );`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try replace:

**From:**

```
fwrite( $create, "<?php $id = $pid; ?>" );
```

**To:**

```
fwrite( $create, '<?php $id = '. $pid .'; ?>' );
```

**PHP strings can be specified in several ways** - see this link stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/4111622 .

**Double quotes strings with variables inside will use the variable `$name` value into the string result.**

```
$name = "cale_b"; 
echo( "My name is $name" ); 
output: "My name is cale_b"
```

**Single quote will not replace it.**

```
echo( 'My name is $name' ); 
output: "My name is $name"
```

Comment: Hi @cale_b, PHP strings can be specified in several ways - see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/4111622 . 

Double quotes strings will replace the variable $name value to the string result.
$name = "cale_b";
echo( "My name is $name" );
output: "My name is cale_b"

Single quote won.'t
echo( 'My name is $name' );
output: "My name is $name"

Comment: this already solve my problem thanks alot

Comment: I added the reference to my answer. If it worked for you guys please vote accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @alertme could you mark it as the answer once it solved your problem?

Comment: @cale_b I explained your doubt editing the answer and it resolved the alertme question. Please let me know if you need anything else. Thank you guys.